# COUNT how many status for every id R

Tags: r

my data look like:

```
ID      status
1       active
1       active
1       suspended
1       exp
2       suspended
2       exp
3       active
3       exp
4       active
4       exp
4       suspended
```

i want to know every id have how much in every case so ishold use count and aggregate
so the data should look like :

```
ID   active     exp     suspended  
1    2          1        1
2    0          1        1
3    1          1        0
4    1          1        1
```

and the final result that i want to extract is
-how many id have active status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tidyverse` approach

```r
library(tidyverse)

read.table(text = "ID      status
1       active
1       active
1       suspended
1       exp
2       suspended
2       exp
3       active
3       exp
4       active
4       exp
4       suspended", header = T) ->df
   
df %>% 
   count(ID, status) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = status, values_from = n) %>% 
   mutate(across(everything(), replace_na, 0))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      ID active   exp suspended
#>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1      2     1         1
#> 2     2      0     1         1
#> 3     3      1     1         0
#> 4     4      1     1         1
```

I case you want to retain the columns you can using `distinct`. Note that `group_by(ID, status) %>% mutate(n = n())` is same as `count(ID, status)`

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(name = "xyz", phone = 5666) %>% 
  group_by(ID, status) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  distinct(ID, status, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = status, values_from = n) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), replace_na, 0))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>      ID name  phone active suspended   exp
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 xyz    5666      2         1     1
#> 2     2 xyz    5666      0         1     1
#> 3     3 xyz    5666      1         0     1
#> 4     4 xyz    5666      1         1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, it works, may i ask a question, if i have more columns other than IDs and status, how can i present them with the result? for example the name and phone number?

Comment: @NoraS I have edited the answer for retaining additional columns

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("ID      status
1       active
1       active
1       suspended
1       exp
2       suspended
2       exp
3       active
3       exp
4       active
4       exp
4       suspended")

dcast( DT, ID ~ status, fun = length )

#    ID active exp suspended
# 1:  1      2   1         1
# 2:  2      0   1         1
# 3:  3      1   1         0
# 4:  4      1   1         1
```

Answer (score 1):

And here is a possible dplyr alternative:

```
#store data
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4)
status <- c('active', 'active', 'suspended', 'exp', 'suspended', 'exp', 'active', 'exp', 'active', 'exp', 'suspended')

#put to a dataframe
df = data.frame('ID' = ID, 'Status' = status)

#group, count, pivot
    df %>%
      group_by(ID, Status) %>% 
      count() %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = Status, values_from=n) %>% 
      replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Output:

```
     ID active   exp suspended
  <dbl>  <int> <int>     <int>
1     1      2     1         1
2     2      0     1         1
3     3      1     1         0
4     4      1     1         1
```

And to get your final result (how many IDs have active status), just add these lines:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID, Status) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Status, values_from=n) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
  filter(active != 0) %>% #filter those that are not 0
  ungroup() %>% #ungroup
  tally() #count
```

Output:

```
      n
  <int>
1     3
```

Comment: If you're using `count` you dont have to `group_by`